# Iterating through a file by creating list of specific sections

Tags: python, file, enumerate

I am new to python and I am trying to iterate through a list and append every 8 lines from a file to a list.  Which I will append to those elements and rewrite this list on a new file.  What I am keep running into is getting specific sections out of the txt file that I want.  Here is my code:

```
tester1=1
tester2=9
for n,line in enumerate(myList):
    if n>(tester1) and n<(tester2):
        tempList.append(line)
        tester1=tester1+8
        tester2=tester2+8
```

So I do not want line 0,1.  But lines 2 through 8.  Next I need it to go to line 9 through 17... and so on.  This current code is giving me every 8th element in my txt file which was made into a list.

Comment: are you trying to end up with a list of lists, like `[[line2,line3,line4,line5,line6,line7,line8],[line9,line10...]]` ?

Comment: Yes I am looking for that, am I on the right track?

Comment: Sorta...  So if you want every 8 lines, except leaving out lines 0 and 1, you'd want lines 2-7, then lines 8-15, then lines 16-23, right?

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: To that 'possible duplicate' it goes into even size list, is there a way to put it into a for loop and exclude lines 0 and 1?

Comment: Yes, just split into even size chunks of 8, then remove the two you don't want.

Comment: Thanks man! I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest possible way, you could do:

```
with open('path/to/file.txt') as f:
    next(f); next(f)  # skip first two lines
    lst = []
    while True:
        try:
            lst.append([next(f) for _ in range(8)])
        except StopIteration:
            return lst
```